# Programmatically print to a PDF printer

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, xps, pdfsharp

I am looking for a free open source .Net based, *preferably C#*, pdf printer such as CutePDF's [Custom PDF Writer with programmatic access](http://www.cutepdf.com/solutions/pdfwriter.asp) that will allow me to save a xps document to a pdf format. I have found many alternatives that are capable of converting xps documents to pdf formats, but they are not open source. I was curious to know if anyone is aware of an open source library that will allow me to accomplish this.

Comment: Take a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395874/convert-xps-to-pdf-in-wpf-c-sharp-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any of you out there attempting to convert XPS to PDF using an open source means, I was able to successfully do so using [PDFSharp version 1.31](http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/releases/view/37054). It successfully upgraded to .NET 4.5 and I included the PdfSharp.Xps project into my solution. Once you include all the references, you only need a single line to link to your XPS file.

`XpsConverter.Convert("D:\\Example\\test.xps");`

Note: There are also other constructors available but I used the most simplistic one in my example.

Hope this helps!