# Convert XPS to PDF using PDFsharp or iTextsharp

Tags: wpf, pdf, pdfsharp, xps

I am trying to convert xps to pdf using PDFsharp.
I have gone through

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848223/wpf-to-xps-to-pdf) &
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002476/best-ways-to-convert-xps-to-pdf-and-vice-versa)

But not able to find steps to convert XPS to PDF. Can anybody suggest me the informative link to convert xps to pdf?

I have downloaded the source of PDFSharp from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/files/pdfsharp/PDFsharp%201.31/)

But what should be next step?
Please help me.
Thanks.

P.S. I have visited all the links related to converting xps to pdf here but as I have low reputation I am not able to post more than 2 links.

UPDATE :
Finally I figured it out.

I followed [this](http://www.nathanpjones.com/wp/2013/03/output-to-pdf-in-wpf-for-free/).

1. download the zips and add dll in your project.
2. use following code

   ```
     MemoryStream lMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
     Package package = Package.Open(lMemoryStream, FileMode.Create);
     XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(package);
     XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
     writer.Write(dp);
     doc.Close();
     package.Close();

     var pdfXpsDoc = PdfSharp.Xps.XpsModel.XpsDocument.Open(lMemoryStream);
     PdfSharp.Xps.XpsConverter.Convert(pdfXpsDoc, FileName, 0);
   ```

   > where dp should be your wpf control.

THEN

```
     PdfSharp.Xps.XpsConverter.Convert(sourceXpsFile, destPdfFile, 0);
```

DONE :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108319) and Nathan Jones [work](https://nathanpjones.com/2013/03/output-to-pdf-in-wpf-for-free/) there is now [a NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XpsToPdf/1.0.0) available to do the trick.

Comment: Nuget package doesn't exist.

Comment: @MartiniBianco the pacakage does not exists, but the package does. I fixed the link.

Comment: Did I really just missed the typo.  Sorry for that. And thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

The next step: UNZIP the file you downloaded. ;-)
Unzip PDFSharp-MigraDocFoundation-1_31.zip.

Go to PDFsharp\dev\XPStoPDF and open the solution there.

In the PdfSharp.Xps.UnitTests project, go to folder XpsFiles and open SampleXpsDocuments_1_0.cs.

The tests in that file show how to convert XPS to PDF.

Comment: Thank you Sir for the answer. (Y) After posting question I gone through http://www.pdfsharp.net/(S(pb3zlpjvn3xe43juqv332hyo))/NuGetPackage_PDFsharp-wpf.ashx and installed package in my wpf application but still looking for the solution.